# Dependent generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I have a `Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<Guid,Component>>` where the key of the outer dictionary is the type of the objects stored in the inner.

I want to get one of the objects in the inner dictionary with a generic method. Something like:

```
public T getObject<T>(Guid id, ???/*typeof(T) passed here*/) where T : Component
```

*How can I constrain the second parameter to be typeof(T) ?*

Comment: Why do you need to pass in the type? Isn't it already accessible through `T`?

Comment: You would just specify the type on the call to the method if it cannot be implied. `var item = getObject<MyType>(id)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Chirs Pickford is saying; there is no need to receive an extra parameter in first place.

When you have generic method like this:

```
public T getObject<T>(Guid id) where T : Component
{
  // you can grab typeof(T) like this
  var type = typeof(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to do it you need to mark your class with T:

```
public class YourClass<T> where T: Component
{ 
    public T getObject<T>(Guid id, T myvalue) ...
```